# Kendo UI Scheduler: An overflow occurred while converting to datetime

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-ui-mvc

I'm developing using .NET MVC and the (**open-source**) Kendo UI Scheduler. I'm trying to save/read/update/delete events from the scheduler into my database using javascript.

But I'm experiencing some trouble: when saving an event from the scheduler to my database I'm getting the following error:

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)   :     System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: An overflow occurred while converting to datetime.**

Also when reading from the database to the scheduler:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTimezoneOffset' of null**

I Googled this but yet found no solution, I followed documentation on: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/scheduler/ajax-editing and read besides that quite all the documentation regarding Telerik Kendo UI Scheduler...

I'm using following code:

**MODEL**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

namespace Eindwerk.Models
{
    public class BookingViewModel : ISchedulerEvent
    {
        [Key]
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        private DateTime start;
        public DateTime Start
        {
            get
            {
                return start;
            }
            set
            {
                start = value.ToUniversalTime();
            }
        }

        private DateTime end;
        public DateTime End
        {
            get
            {
                return end;
            }
            set
            {
                end = value.ToUniversalTime();
            }
        }
        public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
        public int? RecurrenceID { get; set; }
        public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }        
        public bool IsAllDay { get; set; }
        public int? OwnerID { get; set; }
        public string eventRoom { get; set; }
        public string eventAttend { get; set; }
        public string eventExtra { get; set; }
        public string eventRequest { get; set; }

        public class CalendarDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<BookingViewModel> Bookings { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Eindwerk.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Eindwerk.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        private Reports.ReportsDBContext rdb = new Reports.ReportsDBContext();

        // GET: /Reports/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(rdb.Events.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).ToList());
            return View();

        }

        private BookingViewModel.CalendarDBContext db = new BookingViewModel.CalendarDBContext();

        public ActionResult Bookings_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {

            using (var sampleDB = db)
            {
                IQueryable<BookingViewModel> Bookings = sampleDB.Bookings.ToList().Select(task => new BookingViewModel()
                {
                    TaskID = task.TaskID,
                    Title = task.Title,
                    Start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(task.Start, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                    End = DateTime.SpecifyKind(task.End, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                    Description = task.Description,
                    IsAllDay = task.IsAllDay

                }).AsQueryable();
                return Json(Bookings.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


            }
        }

        public ActionResult Bookings_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, BookingViewModel task)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var sampleDB = db)
                {
                    //Create a new Task entity and set its properties from the posted BookingViewModel
                    var entity = new BookingViewModel
                    {
                        TaskID = task.TaskID,
                        Title = task.Title,
                        Start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(task.Start, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                        End = DateTime.SpecifyKind(task.End, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                        Description = task.Description,
                        IsAllDay = task.IsAllDay


                    };


                    // Add the entity
                    sampleDB.Bookings.Add(entity);
                    //sampleDB.Bookings.AddObject(entity);
                    // Insert the entity in the database
                    sampleDB.SaveChanges();

                    // Get the TaskID generated by the database
                    task.TaskID = entity.TaskID;
                }
            }
            // Return the inserted task. The scheduler needs the generated TaskID. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

        public ActionResult Bookings_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, BookingViewModel task)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var sampleDB = db)
                {
                    // Create a new Task entity and set its properties from the posted TaskViewModel
                    var entity = new BookingViewModel
                    {
                        TaskID = task.TaskID,
                        Title = task.Title,
                        Start = task.Start,
                        End = task.End,
                        Description = task.Description,
                        RecurrenceRule = task.RecurrenceRule,
                        RecurrenceException = task.RecurrenceException,
                        RecurrenceID = task.RecurrenceID,
                        IsAllDay = task.IsAllDay,
                        OwnerID = task.OwnerID
                    };
                    // Attach the entity
                    sampleDB.Bookings.Attach(entity);
                    // Change its state to Modified so Entity Framework can update the existing task instead of creating a new one
                    //sampleDB.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    // Or use ObjectStateManager if using a previous version of Entity Framework
                    sampleDB.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    // Update the entity in the database
                    sampleDB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            // Return the updated task. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        public ActionResult Tasks_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, BookingViewModel task)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var sampleDB = db)
                {
                    // Create a new Task entity and set its properties from the posted TaskViewModel
                    var entity = new BookingViewModel
                    {
                        TaskID = task.TaskID,
                        Title = task.Title,
                        Start = task.Start,
                        End = task.End,
                        Description = task.Description,
                        RecurrenceRule = task.RecurrenceRule,
                        RecurrenceException = task.RecurrenceException,
                        RecurrenceID = task.RecurrenceID,
                        IsAllDay = task.IsAllDay,
                        OwnerID = task.OwnerID
                    };
                    // Attach the entity
                    sampleDB.Bookings.Attach(entity);
                    // Delete the entity
                    //sampleDB.Tasks.Remove(entity);
                    // Or use DeleteObject if using a previous versoin of Entity Framework
                    sampleDB.Bookings.Remove(entity);
                    // Delete the entity in the database
                    sampleDB.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            // Return the removed task. Also return any validation errors.
            return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>  
    <script>
          $(function () {
            $('#scheduler').kendoScheduler({
                date: new Date(Date.now()),
                startTime: (new Date(2014, 6, 13, 7, 00, 00)),
                height:800,
                views: [{ type: "day", selected: true }, { type: 'week' }, { type: 'month' }],
                timezone: "Etc/UTC",
                dataSource:
                    {
                        transport:
                        {
                            read: { url: "@Url.Action("Bookings_Read","Home")", dataType: "json" },
                            update: { url: "@Url.Action("Bookings_Update","Home")", dataType: "json" },
                            create: { url: "@Url.Action("Bookings_Create","Home")", dataType: "json" },
                            destroy: { url: "@Url.Action("Bookings_Destroy","Home")", dataType: "json" },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }  
                                }
                        },

                    },
                schema: {

                    model: { 
                        id: "TaskID", 
                        fields: { 
                            TaskID: { type: "int" }, 
                            RecurrenceID: {type:"int?"}

                        } 
                    } 
                },
            group: {
                resources: ["Rooms"]
            },
            resources: [
                 {
                    field: "attendees",
                    name: "Attendees",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "IMD", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                        { text: "IMS", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                        { text: "Toerisme", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                    ],
                    multiple: true,
                    title: "Attendees"
                },

                {
                    field: "roomId",
                    name: "Rooms",
                    dataSource: {
                        transport:
                            {
                                read: { url: "@Url.Action("Rooms_Read","Room")", dataType: "json" }
                            }    
                    }
                }
            ]              
          });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Anybody an idea on how to resolve this error? Or a working illustrative example?

Your help is really appreciated!

---

Database:

[image: database design]

[image: data gets added into db but unable to display in scheduler]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your model looks OK in C#, but what SQL Types are your Start and End fields in your database because the error is happening between SQLServerCE and the C# view model in which it appears.  From [this blog](http://www.jwc3.net/2014/05/kendo-ui-scheduler-with-aspnet-mvc-and.html), the database structure (albeit SQL Server 2012) is shown like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I updated my db to match your example (the types were indeed of datetime instead of datetime2). But this error of  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getTimezoneOffset' of null" occurs.. When I add a record this gets added to my db but I can't seem to display it in the scheduler, I will add examples to my question above.

Comment: Small remark: in my db Meetings the type is set to datetime2(7) but my edmx is still using DateTime? And I can't modify this cause datetime2 is not in the list of types in my edmx... Is this causing the issue? So confusing...

Comment: DateTime2 should be find and if it translates to DateTime?, that just means that the Database column allows NULL values.

Comment: So, for the Kendo Scheduler "events", the Start and [End] should always have a value because it uses those to define the event block (UI) when rendering the schedule. Your DateTime? should actually be DateTime  (does not allow null values).

Comment: My comment was a bit confusing, I meant: in my db Meetings the type is set to datetime2(7) but my edmx is still using DateTime. The question mark was just a question mark I didn't meant DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
timezone: "Etc/UTC";
```

this line seems to screw the scheduler.